# Spring-MVC: Is it possible to have two url-patterns for one servlet-mapping?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have both .htm and .xml URLs that I want to be resolved as .jsp files in my WEB-INF folder. How do I specify that I want the same servlet to handle both *.htm and *.xml URLs?

Answer (score 7):

Adding multiple url-pattern tags in the same mapping works for me using Spring 3.0

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/<url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In regards to making your controllers resolve them to the view objects (.jsp) that you desire you can do so using controllers that extend a controller class and follow a specific naming convention or you can use annotation driven controllers. Below is an example of annotation driven controller.

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value={"/","/index","/index.htm","index.html"})
    public ModelAndView indexHtml() {
        // RETURN VIEW (JSP) FOR HTM FILE
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/index.xml")
    public ModelAndView indexXML() {
        // RETURN VIEW (JSP) FOR XML FILE
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding this can create problem, when you are accessing your images and other icons with the same format "/webapp/icons/calender.jpg". This would create a problem as all of these GET requests will also be directed towards controller.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can very well do that.

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the `<servlet-mapping>` element in your "web.xml" file.

The answer is that you can (sort of) by using two `<servlet-mapping>` elements with different patterns for the same `<servlet>` element.

Note that is a feature of the Java EE Servlet specification.  The associated request dispatching happens before Spring gets a look at the requests.

Comment: I tried that, and I got this error: Feb 10, 2011 11:43:45 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myfirstgrid/invoices.xml] in DispatcherServlet with name 'myfirstgrid'

Comment: Is it better to just have two servlets?

Comment: @ktm5124 - I'd say that that is a different problem.  If the config with two `<servlet-mapping>` elements didn't work, your request wouldn't get to the `DispatcherServlet` at all.  Look at the wiring files / annotations for your application servlets.

Comment: I don't have any annotations because I didn't see any used in the Spring-MVC step-by-step tutorial. Are they necessary for view resolution?